# Rails - link to edit another model within User profiles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've a rails app where Users can list and edit information about the Vehicles they own. A User has_many Vehicles, and a Vehicle belong_to a User.

In the user profile there's a form to create new vehicles.

I'm able to display the list of owned vehicles in the user profile, with a delete link, but when I add a link to the edit action using `edit_vehicle_path`, I only get a link to the vehicle with ID equal to user ID.

users_controller.rb looks like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :correct_user, only: [:show]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @vehicles = @user.vehicles
    @vehicle = current_user.vehicles.build if user_signed_in?
  end

  private

    # before filters

    # Each user can access only his own profile
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user == @user
    end

end
```

vehicles_controller.rb looks like this:

```
class VehiclesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!,  only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,        only: [:destroy, :edit, :update]

  def create
    @vehicle = current_user.vehicles.build(vehicle_params)
    if @vehicle.save
      flash[:success] = "New vehicle added!"
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Houston, we got a problem!"
      render current_user
    end
  end

  def edit
    # @vehicle is already defined in correct_user which is called before_action
  end

  def update
    # @vehicle is already defined in correct_user which is called before_action
    if @vehicle.update_attributes(vehicle_params)
      flash[:success] = "Vehicle updated"
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @vehicle.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Vehicle removed"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

  private

    def vehicle_params
      params.require(:vehicle).permit(:name, :matriculation_date)
    end

    # before filters

    # Each user can remove/edit/destroy only the vehicles he owns
    def correct_user
      @vehicle = current_user.vehicles.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @vehicle.nil?
    end

end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  root 'static_pages#home'
  resources :users,               only: [:show, :index]
  resources :vehicles,            only: [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

end
```

the partial I use to display single vehicle info is:

```
<li id="micropost-<%= vehicle.id %>">
  <span class="name"><%= vehicle.name %></span>
  <span class="matriculation"><%= vehicle.matriculation_date %></span>
  <span class="id"> - id: <%= vehicle.id %></span>
  <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-cog"></i> edit'.html_safe, edit_vehicle_path %>
  <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i> delete'.html_safe, vehicle, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
</li>
```

and the full users/show view is this:

```
<%= form_for(@vehicle) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :name, "Vehicle name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :matriculation_date %>
    <%= f.date_field :matriculation_date, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.submit "Add", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>

<h3>User email: <%= @user.email %></h3>

<% if @user.vehicles.any? %>
    <h3>Vehicles (<%= @user.vehicles.count %>)</h3>
    <ol>
      <%= render @vehicles %>
    </ol>
<% end %>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`edit_vehicle_path` needs to know the `vehicle` to build a proper link. Change it to:

```
<%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-cog"></i> edit'.html_safe, edit_vehicle_path(vehicle) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view it would be better to work with [nested Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

```
resources :users, only: [:show, :index] do
  resources :vehicles, only: [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
end
```

Be awary, this will change your routing helpers and paths as well, but it's more clear, that you edit a users car.

```
edit_user_vehicle_path(@user, @vehicle) 
# => /users/1/vehicles/2/edit
```

Comment: very interesting, I'll definitively give it a try